Trying to implement a closed composition operation for a generic mapped type
I am attempting to build a set of objects that handle different events.
I have defined a generic Event type:
type Event<T extends string = string, D = unknown> = {
  type: T;
  data: D;
}

and a generic (mapped) type for objects that map certain event types to handler functions:
type EventHandlerMap<E extends Event> = {
  [Ev in E as Ev['type']]: (data: Ev['data']) => void
}

I am trying to define a function that composes EventHandlerMap<E1> and EventHandlerMap<E2> into an EventHandlerMap<E1 | E2> without resorting to manual type casting.
I have tried this:
function composeMaps<E1 extends Event, E2 extends Event>(
  eventHandlerMap1: EventHandlerMap<E1>,
  eventHandlerMap2: EventHandlerMap<E2>,
): EventHandlerMap<E1 | E2> {

  return {
    ...eventHandlerMap1,
    ...eventHandlerMap2,
  }

}

But the TypeScript compiler gives me this error:

Type 'EventHandlerMap & EventHandlerMap' is not assignable to type 'EventHandlerMap<E1 | E2>'.(2322)

It seems that this error goes away if I cast the return value to EventHandlerMap<E1 | E2>, but I am trying to avoid manually casting here in case it opens the door to bugs.
Is there a way that I could rejig my approach to help TypeScript infer automatically that EventHandlerMap<E1> & EventHandlerMap<E2> is assignable to EventHandlerMap<E1 | E2> (or similar)?
Playground

I wouldn't expect TS do be able to do the kind of higher order type analysis for generics you're trying to do here; if you're certain you're doing it right, use a type assertion. Otherwise, refactor to use simpler types and rely on TS being able to do the required type analysis for specific types, such as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz, thanks for your thoughts. Your suggestion got me thinking, and I ended up finding a solution based on tweaking the definition of EventHandlerMap slightly -- although this created a different problem! :) I'll post that solution.

(Answering my own question...)
So it turns out that tweaking EventHandlerMap as follows resolves the TypeScript error:
type EventHandlerMap<E extends Event> = {
  // Previously: [Ev in E as Ev['type']]: (data: Ev['data']) => void
  [T in E['type']]: (data: Extract<E, { type: T }>['data']) => void
}

I suppose TypeScript can rationalise this in a way that more closely matches my intent, since it ~iterates over the Event['type']s rather than the Events themselves. This will behave differently in the case where multiple members of the Event union have the same type attribute (but different data attributes).
Playground
